# How to fix:Response is undefined in react-admin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to use react-admin to provide a user CRUD from my API (express)

I followed the steps from react-admin documentation.
    Creating my own DataProvider.
    Inserting Admin component tells me it is properly setup.
    Adding a child Ressource component with users as the ressource name and ListGuesser as the list.

At this point I get a toast saying response in undefined and a console error saying Warning: Missing translation for key: "response is undefined"

I can see in the network tabs that the request is properly sent and  receives a 200 response with the data I expected

I cannot understand it and where it comes from

Here is my adminComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin'
import myDataProvider from './myDataProvider'
import './adminHomepage.css'

let myProvider = myDataProvider('http://localhost:8666')

function AdminHomepage(props) {

  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={myProvider}>
      <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>

  );
}

export default AdminHomepage;
```

Here is my dataProvider

```
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { stringify } from 'query-string';
import {
    fetchUtils,
    GET_LIST,
    GET_ONE,
    CREATE,
    UPDATE,
    DELETE,
    GET_MANY_REFERENCE
} from 'ra-core';

const { getToken } = useAuth();

export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson) => {
  const convertDataRequestToHttp = (type, resource, params) => {
    let url = "";
    const options = {};
    options.headers = new Headers({ Authorization : getToken(), Accept: "application/json" })
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST: {
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/`;
        break;
      }
      case GET_ONE: {
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        break;
      }
      case CREATE: {
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = "POST";
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      }
      case UPDATE: {
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = "PUT";
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      }
      case DELETE: {
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = "DEL";
        break;
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported request type ${type}`);
      }
    }
    return { url, options };
  };

  const convertHttpResponse = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST:
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
        if (!headers.has("content-range")) {
          throw new Error(
            "Content-Range is missing from header, see react-admin data provider documentation"
          );
        }
        let ret = {
          data: json.users,
          total: parseInt(
            headers
              .get("Content-Range")
              .split(" ")
              .pop()
          )
        };
        console.log("RETURN", ret)
        return ret
      }
      case CREATE: {
        return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
      }
      default: {
        return { data: json };
      }
    }
  };

  return (type, resource, params) => {
    const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHttp(type, resource, params);
    return httpClient(url, options).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      convertHttpResponse(response, type, resource, params);
    });
  };
};
```

[Screenshot of my error](https://www.noelshack.com/2019-42-2-1571127636-error.png)

```
 Warning: Missing translation for key: "response is undefined" 
    in Notification (created by Connect(Notification))
    in Connect(Notification) (created by WithStyles(Connect(Notification)))
    in WithStyles(Connect(Notification)) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Context.Consumer (created by translate(WithStyles(Connect(Notification))))
    in translate(WithStyles(Connect(Notification))) (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by WithStyles(Layout))
    in WithStyles(Layout) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)))
    in withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)) (created by Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout))))
    in Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout))) (created by LayoutWithTheme)
    in LayoutWithTheme (created by Route)
    in Route (created by CoreAdminRouter)
    in CoreAdminRouter (created by Connect(CoreAdminRouter))
    in Connect(CoreAdminRouter) (created by getContext(Connect(CoreAdminRouter)))
    in getContext(Connect(CoreAdminRouter)) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by CoreAdminBase)
    in CoreAdminBase (created by withContext(CoreAdminBase))
    in withContext(CoreAdminBase) (at adminHomepage.js:11)
    in AdminHomepage (created by Router.Consumer)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:17)
    in App (at src/​index.js:7)
```

Comment: That image says that signin is required. Why not embed it here?

Comment: I tried to embed it but 10 reputation is required, I'll change the link

Comment: Then just dump the error message in another code bit

Comment: I changed the link, should be accessible now

Comment: Can we have the code for `<Admin />` as well ?

Comment: The code for ```<Admin />``` is from the module react-admin, it's not mine, here's a link https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're forgetting to return the actual result back:

Change your code to:

```js
return (type, resource, params) => {
    const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHttp(type, resource, params);
    return httpClient(url, options).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return convertHttpResponse(response, type, resource, params);
    });
}
```

This bit is probably just to pad the answer.

A `Promise` in JavaScript is just an object which will at some point get resolved to a value. When you do `Promise.then` you're basically returning a new promise which will have a callback triggered when resolved and that callback will receive the resolved property. The new promise your make will have the return value based on the result of the callback given. In your case the final resolved promise would have been `undefined` because nothing was returned in the callback

Comment: Thanks very much that was the key to my problem it's missing from the example code from the documentation though https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.js I had tried it and had an error, that was actually the real error (_id field instead of id) thank you very much

Comment: Actually that's just a quirk with the JS arrow fuctions `() => something` (without the brackets) is shorthand for `() => { return something }`

Comment: Well thanks again... I failed to notice that there was no brackets and didn't know this quirk. You made my day !